# Custom authorization attribute implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In `Asp.Net MVC 5` I was able to do somehting like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // return true or false 
    }
}
```

And then use it as attribute on actions.
Is it possible to do it in `Asp.Net Core 2.1` and if it is, how to do it?

Comment: You are recommended not to do this in ASP.NET Core. It has a different approach to authorization, the docs are pretty good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @user1336 Yes, it is duplicate, I found the solution in your link.